# How to rollback when error occurred in the second query execution| NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, node-modules, rollback

I used to use rollback in `PHP`, I want to implement the same concept in `NodeJS`. I am calling a function that inserts a data to the `database`, and on success I am calling another function from another `Model` to insert data into another `table`.

**My Code**

**`StoreReport`**

```
'use strict';

var sql = require('./db.js');

// IMPORT ANOTHER MODEL
var CashDetailModel = require('./cashDetailModel.js');

var StoreReport =function(storeReport){
    this.store_id=storeReport.store_id;
    this.cash_expense=storeReport.cash_expense_amount;

}

StoreReport.addNewStoreReport = function (report_details,request,result){

    sql.query('INSERT INTO store_report SET ?',report_details, function(err,res){
        if(err){
            result(err,null);
        }else{
            var new_cash_detail = new CashDetailModel(report_details);
            new_cash_detail.store_report_id=res.insertId;
            CashDetailModel.addCashDetail(new_cash_detail,function(err,CashDetailModel){
                if(err){

                  // I NEED TO ROLLBACK IF ERROR OCCURED IN THIS PHASE
                    res.send(err);
                }else{
                    result(null,res.inserted);
                }
            })
        }
    })
}

module.exports = StoreReport;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explained pretty well here: https://know-thy-code.com/transactions-with-multiple-queries-nodejs-mysql/.

You call `sql.beginTransaction()` before the first query and write your queries in the callback for that. Then you can rollback your transaction with `sql.rollback()` or commit the changes with `sql.commit()`.

Comment: I got a 404 for the link

Comment: Above link does not exist

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which mysql engine you are using, transnational engines like innodb considers each query as separate transaction if you are explicitly not defining the transaction.

So in order to revert the change you have two options :

1. Revert changes using update or delete query, which is a wrong approch.
2. Explicitly define transaction using connection.beginTransaction() and commit or rollback accordingly.